# MySQL innodb deadlock on updating two different rows

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I have two different update queries, for eg,

```
UPDATE `logins` SET `logoutTime` = NOW() WHERE `userId` = '13' AND `date` = '2018-07-17'

UPDATE `logins` SET `logoutTime` = NOW() WHERE `userId` = '79' AND `date` = '2018-07-17'
```

which is causing an innodb deadlock. The userId and date field are indexed. No transactions are used for this update query. Both these updates have a select query before the update

```
SELECT count(*) FROM logins WHERE `userId` ='$userId' AND `date` = '2018-07-17'";
```

If the count is 0, it is an insert or else it is an update. The select query does not have any lock clause to it. Why is the above update queries on two different records causing a deadlock?

Comment: "are indexed" -- not precise enough.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: And need to see the whole transaction that includes the `SELECT` and `UPDATE`.